# mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 1205 Lock wait timeout

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to resolve a timeout issue regarding my SQL database. The error occurs in the:

```
SQLUpdate="UPDATE scoutinfo SET patrolID=1 WHERE patrolID=%s"
```

It seems this command takes too long to execute as I receive this error.

```
mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
```

Is their some setting I need to change on MySQL to allow python to update/delete rows in the databae. The database is relatively small (Number of rows in each table <25)

```
SQLPatrolID="SELECT patrolID FROM patrols WHERE patrolname=%s"
mycursor.execute(SQLPatrolID,(DPatrol.get(), ))
myresult=mycursor.fetchall()
PatrolID=myresult[0][0]
print(PatrolID)
SQLUpdate="UPDATE scoutinfo SET patrolID=1 WHERE patrolID=%s"
mycursor.execute(SQLUpdate,(PatrolID, ))
mydb.commit()
print("Success!")
SQLDeletePatrol="DELETE patrolinfo WHERE patrolID=%s"
mycursor.execute(SQLDeletePatrol,(PatrolID, ))
mydb.commit()
```

Any extra information you require I can happily provide.

Comment: This code looks good but is it possible that your forgot to commit a transaction while testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Your query is not taking too long to execute. It's taking too long to acquire a lock on the tuples you are about to update.

What does this mean? There is another query/transaction, updating the exact same records at the same time. It's probably right there on your code, or it's probably a different thread/application. I would think it is the first case though.

You can see who's holding a lock by inspecting these tables:

1. `INNODB_LOCK_WAITS`
2. `INNODB_LOCKS`

Or, run the following command:

```
> show engine innodb status;
```

This will work if you are using INNODB engine. Which you probably are.

Comment: My understanding of the procedural paradigm was that each line of code executes in the order. I thought that each the program would not start the next query until the first one was completed.

Comment: It's exactly like that: each line executes in order @JessiLuckburrow